# how two flutter engine communication with each other

Tags: flutter, miracast

I want to develop one miracast application, can flutter do this?
Otherwise, I need to use two flutter engine, how can they communicate with each other?
If no, I need to use java or swift as a bridge;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can achieve a way to communicate btw two flutter engines with [IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/IsolateNameServer/registerPortWithName.html) and [IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/IsolateNameServer/lookupPortByName.html) methods.